# How to catch all internal errors from external code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I have the following call to an API (an npm module running in Node.js) in a JavaScript file in which I would like to catch all errors so can gracefully handle them. But if I e.g. pass a bad API-KEY or a city name that does not exist, there is an error in the internal code of the API which is not caught by the try/catch:

```
const weather = require('openweather-apis');

const getTemperature = (city, cbSuccess, cbFailure) => {
    try {
        weather.setLang('de');
        weather.setCity(city);
        weather.setUnits('metric');
        weather.setAPPID('BADKEY');
        weather.getTemperature((err, temperature) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`The temperature in ${city} is ${temperature}° C.`);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('there was an error');
    }

}

getTemperature('Berlin');
```

Rather, an error is displayed and execution stops:

```
C:\edward\nwo\jsasync\node_modules\openweather-apis\index.js:162
      return callback(err,jsonObj.main.temp);
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
    at C:\edward\nwo\jsasync\node_modules\openweather-apis\index.js:162:40
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\edward\nwo\jsasync\node_modules\openweather-apis\index.js:250:18)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**Is there a way in JavaScript to catch all errors as one does in e.g. Java and C#?**

Comment: I think that your conceptual problem is the callback, which is obviously called asynchronously, hence outside of the try/catch scope. I believe that you may resolve it via `await` on the `Promise` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that something like this might work:

```
async execute(weather, city, temperature) {
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        weather.getTemperature((err, temperature) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(`The temperature in ${city} is ${temperature}° C.`);
            }
        });
    };
}

const getTemperature = async (city, cbSuccess, cbFailure) => {
    try {
        weather.setLang('de');
        weather.setCity(city);
        weather.setUnits('metric');
        weather.setAPPID('BADKEY');
        const res = await execute(weather, city, temperature);
        console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('there was an error');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not doing what you think it is unfortunately. If you log the error it will show: there was an error:  ReferenceError: temperature is not defined. The api call will never be made in this case.

Comment: @TerryLennox: Please look at the question. Variable `temperature` is not defined in it just as well. It's probably at global scope in the code of this user. This is not the main issue here though. I wrote this example for the user who has asked this question, to take it and fit it into his/her program. I am obviously unable to debug it myself, since I don't think I can access the aforementioned API. But the missing variable definition is not a show stopper in this case. If everything else works for you (i.e., you can access that API), then you can simply declare it and set it to some value.

Comment: my point is only this, that if you remove the temperature variable, you end up with the same issue as before, e.g. TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined. So the outer catch block is not catching the actual exception we wish to catch.

Comment: @TerryLennox: Remove it from where? The declaration of function `execute`? The call to function `execute`? In either case, I believe that the question is targeting external errors, not errors that you intentionally inject into your own code!

Comment: The call would be like so: const res = await execute(weather, city), instead of const res = await execute(weather, city, temperature); And you'd remove it from execute too. It's not accessed there! I'd suggest mocking out the call yourself and see how the code behaves. You could do this with setTimeout.

Comment: @TerryLennox: It IS accessed there, take another look please. And therefore, removing it would be the equivalence of wrecking your own code, which I believe is not the intention here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217384/discussion-between-terry-lennox-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck if an exception throws in asynchronous code. This will stop execution of the script (as you're seeing above).

The module you are using should possibly handle the error in a better way and pass the error in the callback err parameter. Unless you fork the code or file a bug you're stuck with this.

The same effect can be demonstrated here:

```
async function testAsyncException() {
    try { 
        setTimeout(() => { 
            throw new Error("Error in asynchronous code"); 
        }, 100);
    } catch (e) {
        // This will never be caught...
        console.error("testAsyncException: A bad error occurred:", e);
    }
}

process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => { 
    console.log("uncaughtException:", e);
})

testAsyncException();
```

The try .. catch block around the setTimeout call will not handle the generated exception.

The only way you can "catch" this type of exception is using a process event like so:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => { 
    console.log("uncaughtException:", e);
})
```

This however should only be used to log and then exit. Trying to recover program state at this point is not a good idea, since the application is in an unknown state.

If you're using a process manager such as the very useful [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/), the script can be automatically restarted on errors.

Conversely if we try the following:

```
function testSyncException() {
    try { 
        throw new Error("Error in synchronous code");    
    } catch (e) {
        // This will be caught...
        console.error("testSyncException: A bad error occurred:", e);
    }
}

testSyncException();
```

We can see that the exception will be caught.

I strongly recommend this excellent article on error handling by the creators of Node.js (Joyent):

https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors

It details the best strategies for handling both Operational errors and Programmer errors.

Answer (score -1):

> there is an error in the internal code of the API
>
> ```
>   return callback(err,jsonObj.main.temp);
>                                    ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
>   at C:\edward\nwo\jsasync\node_modules\openweather-apis\index.js:162:40
> ```

This is clearly a bug in the *openweather-apis* library. Report it. You hardly will be able to work around it. The library will need to check whether `jsonObj` and `jsonObj.main` exist before attempting to access `.temp` on it, and it should call your callback with an error if the `jsonObj` doesn't look as expected.